# Like button implementation issue

Tags: android

I use the Laika system. The implementation is as follows: The user presses the Like button -> The data from the user ID goes to the Database with the data of the post, at the request of the user who inserts the like -> The like button disappears -> A button is revealed that shows that the like is set, but if the setting itself , then the like should disappear.

The information is placed in the database, the disable like button works perfectly. The problem is in the observations on Like. When checking, the Like button of the post, on which the likes disappear, does not disappear, but the following ones appear in random posts. But if you re-enter, then the information about which post was liked is displayed perfectly. What to do?

```
public class UserPostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserPostAdapter.UserPostViewHolder> {


    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<PostInterface> postInterfaces;

    private  Context context;

    UserPostAdapter(Context context,List<PostInterface> postInterfaces){
        this.postInterfaces = postInterfaces;
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserPostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_pattern, parent,false);
        return new UserPostViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserPostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PostInterface postInterface = postInterfaces.get(position);
        Glide.with(context).load(postInterface.getUserPostImage()).into(holder.userPostImage);
        holder.postDate.setText(postInterface.getPostDate());
        holder.postUserName.setText(postInterface.getPostUserName());
        holder.postText.setText(postInterface.getPostText());
        Glide.with(context).load(postInterface.getPostImage()).into(holder.postImage);
        holder.postId.setText(postInterface.getPostId());
        Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.ic_action_likebefore).into(holder.postLikeBtn);
        Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.ic_action_postlike).into(holder.postLikeBtnSuccess);
        holder.likes.setText(postInterface.getLikes());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return postInterfaces.size();
    }


    class UserPostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView postId;

        private CircleImageView userPostImage;

        private TextView postUserName;

        private TextView postDate;

        private TextView postText;

        private ImageView postImage;

        private ImageView postLikeBtn;

        private ImageView postLikeBtnSuccess;

        private TextView likes;

        private ImageView postComment;

        private DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        public UserPostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            postUserName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userPostName);
            postDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userPostDate);
            postText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userPostText);
            userPostImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userPostImage);
            postImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postImage);
            postId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userPostId);
            postLikeBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postLikeBtn);
            postLikeBtnSuccess = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postLikeBtnSuccess);
            likes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
            postComment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postComment);


            itemView.findViewById(R.id.deletePost).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                            snapshot.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("posts").child(postInterfaces.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPostId()).getRef().removeValue();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });

                }
            });

            itemView.findViewById(R.id.postLikeBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    postLikeBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    postLikeBtnSuccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    databaseReference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("posts").child(postId.getText().toString()).child("likes").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).setValue(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());

                }
            });

            itemView.findViewById(R.id.postLikeBtnSuccess).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    itemView.findViewById(R.id.postLikeBtn).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    itemView.findViewById(R.id.postLikeBtnSuccess).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    databaseReference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("posts").child(postInterfaces.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPostId()).child("likes").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).removeValue();

                }
            });

            databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("posts").child(postInterfaces.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPostId()).child("likes").getChildren()){

                            if(snapshot.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("posts").child(postInterfaces.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPostId()).child("likes").child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).getValue().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())){
                                itemView.findViewById(R.id.postLikeBtn).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                itemView.findViewById(R.id.postLikeBtnSuccess).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }else {
                                itemView.findViewById(R.id.postLikeBtn).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                itemView.findViewById(R.id.postLikeBtnSuccess).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                        }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });


            postComment.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent i = new Intent(context,MyPostsComment.class);
                i.putExtra("postId",postInterfaces.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPostId());
                context.startActivity(i);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I searched in Google for all possible options, none of them suits me, or the result is the same problem

Tried to implement both in ViewHolder and onBindViewHolder. Outcome is the same

I tried to check AddValueListener in Like's OnClick, the application crashed, and addListenerForSingleValueEvent, in this case the system did not work at all

I thought the problem was that the data was being sent to the wrong post. I checked the display of the like when the user revisits the page or application, but when he revisits, the like data is exactly where it should be. The only problem is "Like" button when clicked moment

Comment: Solution:   holder.setIsRecyclable(false);